# How To Elemenate the menu of column of gridpanel ExtJS4

Tags: extjs4

here is my image of my gridpanel :
[image]

just look at the column curativeTask, here I modified the image plus "+" by css:

```
.curative-task >:first-child >.x-column-header-trigger{
      display:block;
      background-image: url('../../resources/images/icon_plus.gif');
}
```

It will be displayed even the user not passed the mouse over it by using "display:block",
Now my probleme is : if I want to clik on this icon I want to do other things but if I cliked on it it show me the menu like this :
[image]

In this case I want to elemenate to show this menu and do other things. I done menuDisable:true but the icon it won't be  displayed even I made "display:block".
So how I Do this else where is others idea ?
https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRhy8.png
Thanks.

Comment: I hope you understood my problem, else I will explain again :(

Comment: Hi, I found a solution wich is : I listen on the event of headertriggerclick and inside that function return false to not show the default menu.